# How can I fund my node in regtest?

Tags: regtest

I am fairly new to bitcoin and was attempting to setup a local test network in my machine. I am using the regtest network to create the local network. Is there a way in which I can initialize the nodes (using a genesis block or something) to hold bitcoins (without mining)?
I was going through the developer docs but I could not figure it out. Pardon me if it is a simple solution as I am fairly new to bitcoin.
Something like an `initialfreecoins=10000000` in the elements/lightning network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there does not such thing as `initialfreecoins=10000000`. However mining on regtest is **not** resource hungry and nearly instant. It's the only way to get coins.

To get coins on regtest you first need a address to *mine* those coins to. An address can be created with
 `bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress`.

To *mine* and payout to this address use with `<address>` being the output of the first step and `<nblock>` the number of blocks you want to mine. A good number would be for example 101 to get 50 coins (because coins need 100 confirmations to be spendable).

`bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress <nblocks> <address>`

You can repeat `generatetoaddress` or set a higher value for `<nblock>` to get more coins.

Comment: So if i set the value of nblocks to a higher value say 500 then the mined fee would also be higher?

Comment: No, you'd mine 500 blocks.